# curried function which takes a function and a list of tuples as input

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

i am trying to define a curried function which takes a function and a list of tuples as input and returns a Boolean value

for example

```
values(fn (x,y:int)=>(x-y) [(5,0)];
val it = true:bool
```

but my problem is i don't know how to pass a dynamic function as an argument.is it possible???help me out.i am a beginner.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass functions as values just like any other. For example:

```
fun values f []      = ...
  | values f (x::xs) = ...
```

Then `f` can be used as if it were a function defined outside of the function.

As a related example, here is a function that takes an `x` and a list of functions `[f1, f2, ..., fn]` and applies each function in the list to `x`:

```
fun values x [] = []
  | values x (f::fs) = f x :: values x fs
```